# How would one compute this complex contour integral: $\int_\Gamma(Log(z))^2dz$ along the line segment $z=1$ to $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to calculate: $\int_\Gamma(Log(z))^2dz$ along the line segment $z=1$ to $z=i$.

Would I break the $Log$ up into its $ln$ and $arg$ components and integrate them separately? If so, I'm not too sure how to integrate an argument...

Thanks!

Comment: try plugging in a parametrization explicitely and the derivative and compute it out?

Comment: or you could find the antiderivative that is valid on the contour..

Comment: I was thinking about trying that method, but this section of the book we are using the Fundamental theorem of Calculus, i.e. We want to plug in the end points ($z=1$ and $z=i$) into the integral of $Log^2(z)$.

Comment: Yeah so find an anti-derivative on some branch of log(z) and apply FTC

Comment: That's the problem. What is the anti-derivative of the complex logarithm?

Comment: The normal chain-rule and whatnot still work with complex logarithms because they are analytic on some branch that you fix. Log(z) itself is usually referred to as a multi-valued function which is not really a function at all. Use normal calculus and anti-derivatives pretending that Log(z) is just logz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anti-derivative of $\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}f(z) = (\Log z)^2$ is 
$$
F(z) = z(\Log z)^2 -2z\Log z + 2z
$$
which you can verify by differentiating. (Note that the deriviative of any branch of the complex logarithm is $1/z$.)

Assuming that $\Log$ denotes the principal branch of the logarithm, $F$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of the line segment you are integrating along, so the integral is simply $F(i)-F(1)$.